Keeping track of separate flows in python async code
I have some python async code that emits log lines to document its progress. However, multiple instances of the same code might be running at the same time, so log lines are also intermixed. I would like to assign a unique identifier (a UUID, whatever) to each running task/instance that I can prepend to its log lines, so that logs can later be postprocessed to separate the various logs.
The code also calls functions in other modules, which in turn also emit log lines, so the usual idiom for module logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

at the beginning of the module doesn't work for this case. I have access to the code of all modules, so I can make the needed changes.
The question is: how do I configure logging so that each task gets a unique id, writes it to each of its log lines and propagates it to called modules so they can add it to their log lines?

Have you seen https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#adding-contextual-information-to-your-logging-output?

Thanks. On that page I don't see information on how to make called modules use the same (multiple) context configuration(s) as the caller, though.

So in the end this was done using context variables, each module exposes a contextvar for the caller module to transmit the parent context, and another contextvar for the module's local context. The context is updated when needed and dynamically computed when logging. Sample code:
# module.py
from contextvars import ContextVar
import logging
# import submodule

caller_context = ContextVar('caller_context', default=None)
my_context = ContextVar('my_context', default=None)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(context)s | %(message)s")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
f = ContextFilter()
logger.addFilter(f)
logger.addHandler(handler)

def get_current_context():
    ctx = []
    if caller_context.get() is not None:
        ctx.append(caller_context.get())
    ctx.append(my_context.get())
    return ' | '.join(ctx)

class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        record.context = get_current_context()
        return True

async def do_something():
    my_context.set("module context")
    # set caller_context of called modules if needed
    # submodule.caller_context.set(get_current_context())    

    logger.info("Doing something in the module...")
    # main context | module context | Doing something in the module...

# main.py

from contextvars import ContextVar
import asyncio
import logging
import module

my_context = ContextVar('my_context', default=None)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(context)s | %(message)s")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
f = ContextFilter()
logger.addFilter(f)
logger.addHandler(handler)

def get_current_context():
    return my_context.get()

class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        record.context = get_current_context()
        return True

async def main():
    my_context.set("main context")
    module.caller_context.set(get_current_context())

    logger.info("In the caller...")
    # main context | In the caller...

    result = await module.do_something()

    logger.info(f"The returned value is {result}")
    # main context | The returned value is ...

asyncio.run(main())

This allows complete tracing of the call chains, chaining any number of modules, provided each coroutine correctly updates the contexts it'll be using at the beginning (that is, its own context plus those of any modules it will call).
At the same time, modules can also be called from non-concurrent contexts (ie, where the caller doesn't modify the callee caller_context) and in those case will just log normally with only its context.
Simpler solutions are welcome.
